# Memory usage increases with every record read

Tags: memory, orm, cakephp-3.0

I have a couple of database management tasks that need to go through every record in the database. It was my understanding that with the CakePHP 3.x ORM, I could do something like this, and it would only ever have one record in memory at a time:

```
$records = TableRegistry::get('Whatever')->find();
foreach ($records as $record) {
    // do some processing
}
```

However, this is eventually crashing with an "out of memory" exception. I've added a bit of logging of `memory_get_peak_usage`, and it's increasing with every iteration, even if there is nothing other than the logging happening inside the foreach loop. The delta is around 12K every time through the loop.

I'm running 3.2.7, and results are similar whether I have debugging and/or SQL logging enabled or not. Adding frequent calls to `gc_collect_cycles()` only slows the process down, it doesn't help with the memory usage.

Is this expected, or a bug? If the former, is there anything I can do differently *in this code* to prevent it? (Obviously, I could process it in smaller batches, but that's not an elegant solution.)

Comment: Have you tried turning off [**result buffering**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#working-with-result-sets)?

Comment: @ndm, that sounded promising, so I ran a couple of quick tests, but some strangely seemed to show the memory usage increasing *faster* with buffering turned off. Entirely possible that I did something wrong in my test... Other tests crashed, telling me "Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active.", which may be a deal-breaker for me, in this particular situation. I'll have to think on it and see if there's a solution to that which is less intrusive to the code than running the big query I need to do in small batches would be.

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP 3.x ORM has built in query caching for the `ResultSet` object. When you iterator over the result set the entities are stored in an internal array. This is done so that you can rewind the iterator and loop again.

If you are going to iterate over a large result set only once, and you want to reduce memory usage then you have to disable result buffering.

```
$records = TableRegistry::get('Whatever')->find()->bufferResults(false);
foreach ($records as $record) {
    // do some processing
}
```

With buffering turned off the entity is fetched from the result set and there should be no references to it afterwards.

Documentation for this feature is available in the CakePHP book: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#working-with-result-sets

Here's the API reference: https://api.cakephp.org/3.6/class-Cake.Database.Query.html#_bufferResults

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding it is the expected behaviour, as you execute the query build with the ORM when you start iterating over the object($records). Thus all the data is loaded into memory, and you then iterate over each entry one by one.

If you want to limit the memory usage I would suggest you look into [limit](http://api.cakephp.org/3.1/class-Cake.Datasource.QueryInterface.html#_limit) and [offset](http://api.cakephp.org/3.1/class-Cake.Datasource.QueryInterface.html#_offset). With these you can extract subsets to work on, thus limiting memory usage.

Comment: I thought the new ORM would only retrieve records one at a time, when used in this manner. If I called `toArray` on the result set, then for sure it would load everything at once, but the fact that it's increasing as it goes along seems to indicate that it hasn't.

Comment: I think you are confusing the [lazy evaluation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#how-are-queries-lazily-evaluated). I'm not an expert on the ORM but I'm pretty sure studying the [query builder](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html) and [collections](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/collections.html) will help you optimise your query:) Also I just watched [Advanved querying](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rBRy5BiCeew) which sort of demonstrates the power of the ORM. Might be useful to you too:)

Comment: If it were retrieving all of the records into memory at once and then going through them one at a time, it would crash immediately. (Or, if I read a smaller number, the memory would jump to its peak usage right away and then just sit there relatively unchanged.) The fact that the memory usage increases by a steady amount with every iteration until it crashes tells me that it's fetching only one record at a time, but not disposing of the object when I go on to the next one. This is very clear to me; perhaps I'm not explaining it well.